# Printing All Code in Eclipse at once

Tags: eclipse, printing

Is there a way to print all of the code scripts in my project in eclipse at once? Right now I am stuck with printing each file one by one.

Comment: I guess it's for a college report. If that's the case, then you should do it one file at a time. Eclipse is not supposed to help you with your project report which needs your code to be printed on paper. I wonder where else would you want to print out all your programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921178/print-the-sourcecode-of-a-whole-java-project) thread. It is explained how to print the whole code of a project using `enscript`. If you are using Windows, you need to install cygwin.